# How to remove entries of a numpy array based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm currently working on an optimization problem and I'm stuck at some point.

Here is a simple case:
I have a set of `p` parameters in `c` combinations and try to optimize them on `i` inputs. This leads to a numpy array of shape `(p, c, i)`. For each of them, I calculate an error leading to a second array of shape `(c, i)`. Now I have to get rid of some combinations before running the next iteration.

For the case `i = 1`, I use the following code which works fine (arrays are just `(p, c)` and `(c, )`):

```
ensemble = np.vstack((ensemble, error))
# Remove some functions that do not fit
ensemble = ensemble[:, ensemble[p, :] < thres]
# Delete error column
function_ensemble = np.delete(function_ensemble, p, axis=0)
```

Now I try to generalize this for `i > 1`:

```
error[error >= 0.015] = 0
error = error[np.newaxis, :, :]
# Maybe keep them seperate
ensemble = np.concatenate((ensemble, error))
```

And thats where I'm stuck. What I'm currently thinking of is sorting my `ensemble` by the `error` and removing all entries where the error is `0` for all `i`. So that the `ensemble` gets smaller. However, as far as I know, `np.sort` does not work here. Maybe I could use structured arrays but I'm not sure if this would destroy code in other places.

Does anyone have an idea for my issue?

---

**Edit**

For case `i=1` a running example with `p=3` and `c=100` could just be:

```
error = np.random.rand(100)
ensemble = np.ones([3, 100])

ensemble = np.vstack((ensemble, error))
ensemble = ensemble[:, ensemble[3, :] < 0.5]
ensemble = np.delete(ensemble, 3, axis=0)
```

The result in this case is a subset of my ensemble where the error is smaller than 0.5.

For case `i=2` (multiple ensembles) an example with `p=3` and `c=100` could be:

```
error = np.random.rand(100, 2)
ensemble = np.ones([3, 100, 2])

error[error >= 0.015] = 0
error = error[np.newaxis, :, :]
ensemble = np.concatenate((ensemble, error))
```

Again, I want a subset of my ensembles containing all sets of parameters with an error < 0.5. This will require some padding since each ensemble `i` will have a different size afterwards.
However, the ultimate goal is to iterate and adjust the parameters until only one set remains ending up with an array of size `(3,1,2)`. (Examles above do not show iteration).

Best, Julz

Comment: It would best if you posted a sample set of your data, the results are currently getting and the results you need. It’s very difficult frame the problem and envision a solution without data.

Comment: Alright, I've added some simple data.